# android Retrofit and OkHttpClient Error SSL handShake on a backend with let's encrypt certification

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, lets-encrypt, okhttp

I really don't know how to fix this, this project it's an Android and iOs app with a RoR backend API on a Docker container server...

In the Android app, I used Retrofit Library for the api client implementation, and everything was working perfectly... Until the SSL Certificate was implemented on the server. My partner used [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for that, I can make request successfully on the api with curl, postman... but my android app always say:

```
D/Error: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xXXXXXXXX: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

or sometimes:

```
D/Error: SSL handshake timeout
```

The ApiClient source:

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String DOMAIN = "qwerty.xyz"; //not the real url obviously
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api." + DOMAIN;

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .create();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}

public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


        OkHttpClient okHttpClient  = httpClient.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                                                            return true;
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .build();

        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

An observation, the sslSocketFactory method is Deprecated... But I don't know how is the new way to do it...

I'm using the 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'...

I really appreciate any help to find the solution.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

Let's Encrypt use TLSv1.2 protocol and not self signed, we need to exclude older's version of TSL.

I create a Custom SSLSocketFactory to do this:

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

and then we and this in the httpclient with a trust manager:

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
                }
            } };
            client = httpClient.sslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0])
                    .build();
            Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client)
                    .build();
```

and voila!!

Comment: Do you have the .crt file for SSL? You can also include the .crt file locally and add it into your OkHttp client.

Comment: The certification it's not static, it's always refreshing

Comment: You should check the enabled ciphers on your server. Also, is there any reason you're trying to circumvent the cert validation?

Comment: i'm trying to circumvent the cert validation?

Comment: > I'm trying to circumvent the cert validation? 
for anyone reading this, the answer is YES, this TrustedManager implementation doesn't do anything and accepts any certificate. Latest versions of Android Studio even shows a warning when you copy-paste this code into your project.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on once [certificate pinning](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

Comment: Not a proper solution for Retrofit2 also a linked only answer!